# Regular expression to match email except for specific email address(es)

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will match email addresses, but exclude specific email addresses from the match

e.g. Do not match (exclude these addresses from match);

```
sponge.bob@example.com
jim.bob@example.com
billy.bob@example.com
```

match all other email addresses (include any other valid email address);

```
test@example.com
no.body@example.com
another.test.email@example.com
and.another.one@example.com.au
```

I tried using a negative lookbehind expression but couldn't figure out how to get it working (if even possible via that method). It would be beneficial to be able to specify multiple excluded emails, but at least one exclusion would be minimum required.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to match, and what do you not want to match? Edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))(?!sponge\.bob@example\.com|jim\.bob@example\.com|billy\.bob@example\.com)(\w[\w\.]*@\w+\.[\w\.]+)\b
```

See demo [here.](https://regex101.com/r/OGc1mQ/1)

---

**explanation**

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))                   //appears at start of line or after space
(?!                             //Don't match if it starts with the below
sponge\.bob@example\.com|
jim\.bob@example\.com|
billy\.bob@example\.com
)                               //End exclusions
(                               //Capture group for emails, you don't need this
\w                              //Start with [A-Za-z0-9_]
[\w\.]*                         //Zero or more of [w\.]
@
\w+                             //Start with one or more [A-Za-z0-9_]
\.                              //Forces to have atleast one dot
[\w\.]+                         //followed by one or more of [\w\.]
)                               //End capture group for emails, remove it with the matching group
\b                              //Should end with word boundary.
```

Comment: Impressive, could you please explain why this part makes the following expressions work (?:^|(?<=\s)). I don't understand how that effects the overall capture

Comment: It just forces the email address to start at beginning of a line `^` or at after space `\s`. Otherwise it will match `bob@example.com` even though it came as `sponge.bob@example.com`

Comment: Actually that makes me think it would be robust if we force a space or end of line as an email address trailing boundary. I will leave that to you.

Comment: Currently it is a loose `\b` so it will match `a.b@c.d` in `a.b@c.d.`

Comment: Also I would include a `-`  with `\w` as I think it is a valid char in an email address am not sure.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was the problem I was having when I tried making my own expression, partial captures still happened for emails I didn't want captured. e.g. ponge.bob@example.com. I had tried using word boundaries to avoid that problem, but that didn't work because of the possible . between words in some email addresses which are considered a boundary. Your solution is very clever, thanks for your assistance.