# Regex to match email username except for 10 consecutive digits (or 11 if it starts with 1)

Tags: regex, email-validation

I need a regex for my email validator. I do not want to allow users to enter whole phone numbers as `email` username. If the user enters all numbers:

```
123456789@test.com // allowed (9 digits or less)
01234567890@test.com // allowed (11 digits but not starting with 1)
123456789012@test.com // allowed (12 digits or more)

0123456789@test.com // NOT allowed (10 digits)
11234567890@test.com // NOT allowed (11 digits and starting with 1)
```

There is a great close answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46657010) which I tried

```
<input 
    type="email" 
    pattern="(?:^|(?<=\s))(?!\d{10}|1\d{10})(\w[\w\.]*@\w+\.[\w\.]+)\b"
/>
```

But the exclude part `(?!\d{10}|1\d{10})` does not work for me. I want to allow 12 or more digits.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding a negative lookahead to your regex as shown below:

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))(?!1?\d{10}@)(\w[\w\.]*@\w+\.[\w\.]+)\b 
             -------------
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uvgCKQ/2)**

I have just added the subpattern `(?!1?\d{10}@)` to your regex which does not allow the current position to be followed by (an optional digit `1` followed by 10 more digits followed by @)